# Solution check for function series uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I would like to know if I solved the question correctly:

I wish to check if the series of function $x^n-x^{2n}$ converge uniformly when $0\le x\le 1$.

My solution:

The limit function is $f(x)=0$ when $0\le x\le 1$

So if $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}sup|x^n-x^{2n}-0|=0$ the series converge uniformly.

I found that the function has a maximum point when $x= \frac{1}{2}^{\frac{1}{n-1}}$

so when we plug in that point we get  $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}sup|x^n-x^{2n}-0|=\frac{1}{4} $ so the series does not converge uniformly.

if $\frac{1}{3}\le x \le \frac{1}{2} $ the function indeed converge uniformly since the maximum point is not in that range.

If I made any mistakes please let me know.

Comment: The terms don't converge uniformly to $0$ for $x\in (0,1)$, but do converge uniformly on all compact subsets of $(0,1)$.

Comment: @MarkViola true but is my way of solution is right?

Comment: Not quite.  If the series converges uniformly, then the general terms must approach $0$ uniformly.  The converse is not generally true.